Proving an identity for flagged Schur without use of determinants?
In proposition 3 of Determinantal transition kernels for some interacting particles on the line, Dieker and Warren prove the following identity: consider vector $a:=(a_1,\dotsc,a_N)$ and kernels
$$\Lambda(z,y):=\det[h_{z_{i}-y_{j}-i+j}(0,\dotsc,0,a_{j+1},\dotsc,a_{N})],$$
where when $j=N$, we set $h_{z_{i}-y_{j}-i+j}(0,\dotsc,0,a_{j+1},...,a_{N}):=1_{z_{i}-y_{j}-i+j=0}$
and
$$\Pi(z,y):=\det[(-1)^{z_{i}-y_{j}-i+j}e_{z_{i}-y_{j}-i+j}(0,\dotsc,0,a_{i+1},\dotsc,a_{N})],$$
where when $i=N$, we set $e_{z_{i}-y_{j}-i+j}(0,\dotsc,0,a_{i+1},\dotsc,a_{N}):=1_{z_{i}-y_{j}-i+j=0}$.
Then via the Cauchy–Binet identity they show

$$\sum_{y\in W_{N}}\Lambda(y,x)\Pi(z,y)=1_{x=z},\tag{$*$}\label{475841_star}$$
where $W_{N}:=\{y\in Z^{N}: y_{N}\leq \dotsb\leq y_{1}\}$.

We can write \eqref{475841_star} in terms of Schur polynomials (flagged). By using the Jacobi–Trudi identity for flagged Schur for flags $f_{1}:=(2,\dotsc,N)$ and $f_{2}:=(N,\dotsc,N)$ we have
$$\Lambda(z,y)=s_{z/y}(f_{1},f_{2};a)=\sum_{T, \operatorname{sh}(T)=z/y}a^{w(T)},$$
where we sum over semistandard tableaux $T$ whose shape is given by the skew diagram $z/y$ such that the entries in row $1\leq i\leq N-1$ must be from the set $\{i+1,\dotsc,N\}$. And similarly for flags $f_{3}:=(1,\dotsc,1)$ and $f_{4}:=(N-1,\dotsc,1)$ we have
$$\Pi(z,y)=s_{z/y}^{*}(f_{3},f_{4};-a_{N+1-\bullet})=\sum_{T, \operatorname{sh}(T)=z^{t}/y^{t}}(-a_{N+1-\bullet})^{w(T)},$$
where we sum over semistandard tableaux $T$ whose shape is given by the conjugate skew diagram $z^{t}/y^{t}$ and the entries in column $1\leq j\leq N-1$ must be from the set $\{1,\dotsc,N-j\}$ and we had to revert the weights to
$$-a_{N+1-\bullet}:=(-a_{N},-a_{N-1},\dotsc,-a_{1}).$$ (This change of index was done in order to match the notation from pg. 30 Schur functions : Theme and variations by Macdonald, pg. 13 in Flagged Schur functions, Schubert polynomials, and symmetrizing operators by Wachs and Flagged Schur polynomial duality via a lattice path bijection by McDowell).
Alternatively, as mentioned in the comments, we have
$$\Pi(z,y)=s_{z/y}^{*,co}(f_{3},f_{4};-a_{N+1-\bullet})=\sum_{T\in co-SYT, \operatorname{sh}(T)=z/y}(-a_{N+1-\bullet})^{w(T)},$$
where we instead sum over co-semistandard tableaux $T$ (that is, tableaux that strictly increase along rows and weakly increase down columns) whose shape is given by the skew diagram $z/y$ and the entries in row $1\leq i\leq N-1$ must be from the set $\{1,\dotsc,N-i\}$.
Therefore, \eqref{475841_star} translates to the following identity for two row-flagged Schur polynomials

$$\sum_{\mu\subseteq \nu\subseteq \lambda}s_{\lambda/\nu}(f_1,f_2;a)s_{\nu/\mu}^{*,co}(f_{3},f_{4};-a_{N+1-\bullet})=1_{\lambda=\mu},\tag{$**$}\label{475841_starstar}$$
where we sum over all partitions between partitions $\lambda$, $\mu$.

As mentioned in the comments: in the co-SSYT $T_{1}$ with shape $\nu/\mu$, we reflect the entries from $k$ to $N+1-k$ and so its entries at row $i$
are from the set $\{i+1,...,N\}$. Denote this as $Ref(T_{1})$. This means that the combined tableau $Ref(T_{1})$ with tableau $T_{2}$ from $\Lambda$, will have the same row-flag condition.

Q: Is there any way to prove \eqref{475841_starstar} without the Cauchy–Binet identity or other determinant-specific identities? Is there some proof that purely uses Young-Tableaux and orthogonality/basis/duality/branching properties?

The motivation is that we are studying cylindrical skew diagrams and we want to prove \eqref{475841_starstar} for them but here we deal with sums of determinants (see proposition 1 in Cylindric partitions by Gessel and Krattenthaler).
Attempt: One idea is try to get some branching rules for flagged $s_{\lambda/\nu}(a,b;p)$
$$\sum_{\mu\subseteq \nu\subseteq \lambda}s_{\lambda/\nu}(a,b;p)s_{\nu/\mu}(c,d;x)=s_{\lambda/\mu}(\dotsc),$$
and then some duality relation between $s_{\lambda/\nu}(a,b;p)$ and $s_{\nu/\mu}^{*}(c,d;-p)$.

Well there’s a way to phrase everything in terms of non-intersecting paths in some planar network, and then appeal to the Lindström-Gessel-Viennot lemma, but of course that is also about determinants.

@SamHopkins Indeed, I am trying to avoid the paths determinant formulations because they don't carry through in our cylindrical setting (they end up being sums of determinants). I am wondering if there is some proof that purely uses Young-Tableaux and orthogonality/basis/duality properties, which might still be present in the cylindrical case.

Note that there has been some recent work on extending LGV-type techniques to graphs on cylinders: see e.g. https://arxiv.org/abs/2102.07229.

@SamHopkins thank you. But yes we particularly use the lattice-paths in the Gessel-Krattenthaler formulas involving sums of determinants. And these don't have corresponding Cauchy-Binet identities.

This looks a lot like a case for sign-reversing involutions.

The simplest approach appears to be considering the semistandard tableaux of shapes $\lambda / \nu$ and $\nu / \mu$ as one single semistandard tableau of shape $\lambda / \mu$, and fixing the latter. Then, the only sum that remains is a sum over all possible partitions $\nu$ that lie between $\mu$ and $\lambda$ and make the flagging conditions true for our tableau. Is this sum always $1$ or $0$ ? Can we prove it by toggling a single cell between the above-$\nu$ and below-$\nu$ parts? We would need to find a toggleable cell $\left(i,j\right)$ with entry lying in $\left[i+1,N-j\right]$.

By the way, are you sure about $s_{z/y}^{*}(c,d,-p)=\det((-1)^{z_{i}-y_{j}-i+j}e_{z_{i}-y_{j}-i+j} (p_{i+1},...,p_{N})    )$? This makes it sound like the entries in column $i$ should lie between $i+1$ and $N$, whereas your definition makes them lie between $1$ and $N-i$. Or does your $-p$ include flipping the order of the $p$'s as well?

@darijgrinberg Thank you. I added a couple more references for that identity. Exactly, I also had to flip the order of the p's (I rewrote the weights more carefully to clarify that).

@darijgrinberg can you explain a bit your intuition with the toggling? Are you trying to get cancelations across different terms $s_{\lambda/\nu}(a,b;p)s_{\nu/\mu}^{*}(c,d,-p)$ in the above (i.e. constructing a sign-reversing involution as in the LGV argument)?

Yes. See, e.g., the proof of Lemma 6.5 in https://arxiv.org/abs/1509.08355v3 for a similiar situation (but without flagging).

@darijgrinberg is it possible to give a "partial answer" below at least maybe putting the above problem in the language from your lemma 6.5 to help me understand better? I would love to hear more about your toggleable cell approach.

I have given up on the problem once I realized I really couldn't work with your notation, sorry. Can you restate it maximally explicitly, without any substitutions?

@darijgrinberg ok thank you, I rewrote the whole post. The notation is a bit annoying because I am trying to match the literature. Please let me know if it is still not legible or if you have some suggestions on how to rewrite it better.

Much better! I'm seeing that my argument doesn't work here directly, since the flag conditions differ below versus above $\nu$, but there might be a way to adapt. I'll let you know if I figure this out; it's an interesting problem for sure!

@darijgrinberg thank you. Even some partial heuristic would be helpful so that I can test it. Some other person suggested RSK: "You might want to look into RSK though, as this is a combinatorial way to prove Cauchy-like identities." Also, the ( * * )-identity I wrote it myself so I might have made some mistake. I simply wanted to write ( * ) in terms of Schur-flag.

Ah, I think I see where the confusion is coming from. Your $s^*_{z/y}$ is not a sum over semistandard tableaux of shape $z/y$, but rather a sum over cosemistandard tableaux of shape $z/y$ (that is, tableaux that strictly increase along rows and weakly increase down columns), or, equivalently, a sum over semistandard tableaux of shape $z^t/y^t$ (where $^t$ means conjugation). Using the first point of view, I hope (haven't checked with the literature) that the choice of variables in $\Pi\left(y,z\right)$ corresponds to a row-flagging (not a column-flagging). If so, then ...

... you're ultimately summing over pairs of a semistandard tableau of shape $\lambda/\nu$ and a cosemistandard tableau of shape $\nu/\mu$ that are both subject to row-flagging conditions. If you appropriately reflect the entries of the latter (i.e., replace each $k$ by $N+1-k$) and combine the two tableaux, you get a form of "split tableau" that is strictly decreasing along rows until $\nu$ and then weakly increasing along rows afterwards, and is weakly decreasing down columns until $\nu$ and then strictly increasing down columns afterwards. And I think the row-flagging conditions should ...

... then match up precisely, though this needs to be checked. If this all works out, then the result follows from Lemma 6.5 in my paper (and thus should generalize to cylindric tableaux and P-partitions in general). If you rewrite your question with the correct combinatorial interpretation of $s^*_{z/y}$, then I can elaborate on this.

@darijgrinberg You are right, I am sorry. I forgot to add the "conjugate" as mentioned in the literature. I updated it.  And I see that indeed this is the same as summing over cosemistandard with now row-flagging.
Yes, if possible please give me at least a partial heuristic to understand the connection.

@darijgrinberg if possible, please explain to me a bit the way you are thinking to express the above problem in terms of the double poset in your lemma 6.5. My guess is you want the $\nu/\mu$ to be one ordering and $\lambda/\nu$ the other ordering. Is then $\pi$ assigning the entries to the tableaus? What's your guess on how the weights $a$ show up in that formulation?

I will elaborate on this in a proper answer -- just need some more time. Sorry for the wait!

I'll pipe in to add I recently proved a similar lemma, but with the flagging only on one set of variables. The basic idea is a sign-reversing involution: you should be able to view the monomials in each $\Pi$ as a co-semistandard tableau with negative entries and monomials in each $\Lambda$ as a semistandard tableau with positive entries, both satisfying flag conditions. Concatenate these tableaux and the existence of an entry whose sign can change while preserving the tableaux conditions will give a sign-reversing involution.

@ZachH That would be nice to see too. Can you add a reference?

@darijgrinberg yes that would be very interesting, especially since it might generalize to cylindrical case too.

I've made some further corrections, hopefully correct ones (but please double-check!).

Here is the argument that I was hinting to in the comments. I suspect that
this is the same argument @ZachH has in mind, but I hope to have avoided the
many opportunities to get signs and conjugates wrong at last.
The first step is to rewrite $\Pi\left(  z,y\right)  $ further. Namely, let me
define an anti-cosemistandard tableau (short: anti-coSSYT) to be a
tableau whose entries strictly decrease along rows and weakly increase
along columns. Now, I claim that
\begin{equation}
\Pi\left(  z,y\right)  =\sum_{\substack{P\text{ is an anti-coSSYT}\\\text{of
shape }z/y;\\\text{all entries in row }i\text{ of }P\text{ are }>i}}\left(
-a\right)  ^{w\left(  P\right)  }
\label{eq.darij2.1new}
\tag{1}
\end{equation}
for any partitions $y$ and $z$ (where $-a:=\left(  -a_{1},-a_{2},\ldots
,-a_{N}\right)  $). Indeed, this follows from the equality
\begin{equation}
\Pi\left(  z,y\right)  =\sum_{\substack{T\text{ is a coSSYT}\\\text{of shape
}z/y;\\\text{all entries in row }i\text{ of }T\text{ are }\leq N-i}}\left(
-a_{N+1-\bullet}\right)  ^{w\left(  T\right)  }
\label{eq.darij2.1old}
\tag{2}
\end{equation}
via the substitution that replaces every entry $k$ of the coSSYT by $N+1-k$.
(This substitution has the effect of turning coSSYTs into anti-coSSYTs and
vice versa, and also sends $\left(  -a_{N+1-\bullet}\right)  ^{w\left(
T\right)  }$ to $\left(  -a\right)  ^{w\left(  P\right)  }$ because the
exponent on $-a_{N+1-k}$ becomes the exponent on $-a_{k}$.) Furthermore, the
addend $\left(  -a\right)  ^{w\left(  P\right)  }$ in \eqref{eq.darij2.1new}
can be rewritten as $\left(  -1\right)  ^{\left\vert z/y\right\vert
}a^{w\left(  P\right)  }$ (since $\left\vert w\left(  P\right)  \right\vert
=\left\vert z/y\right\vert $). Thus, \eqref{eq.darij2.1new} rewrites as
\begin{equation}
\Pi\left(  z,y\right)  =\left(  -1\right)  ^{\left\vert z/y\right\vert }
\sum_{\substack{P\text{ is an anti-coSSYT}\\\text{of shape }z/y;\\\text{all
entries in row }i\text{ of }P\text{ are }>i}}a^{w\left(  P\right)
}.
\label{eq.darij2.1newest}
\tag{3}
\end{equation}
As you have already observed, we furthermore have
\begin{equation}
\Lambda\left(  y,x\right)  =\sum_{\substack{T\text{ is an SSYT}\\\text{of
shape }y/x;\\\text{all entries in row }i\text{ of }T\text{ are }
>i}}a^{w\left(  T\right)  }
\label{eq.darij2.2}
\tag{4}
\end{equation}
(where "SSYT" means "semistandard tableau"). Thus, for any three partitions
$x\subseteq y\subseteq z$, we have
\begin{align}
&\Lambda\left(  y,x\right)  \Pi\left(  z,y\right)    \\
& =\left(  \sum
_{\substack{T\text{ is an SSYT}\\\text{of shape }y/x;\\\text{all entries in
row }i\text{ of }T\text{ are }>i}}a^{w\left(  T\right)  }\right)  \cdot\left(
-1\right)  ^{\left\vert z/y\right\vert }\sum_{\substack{P\text{ is an
anti-coSSYT}\\\text{of shape }z/y;\\\text{all entries in row }i\text{ of
}P\text{ are }>i}}a^{w\left(  P\right)  }\nonumber\\
& =\left(  -1\right)  ^{\left\vert z/y\right\vert }\sum_{\substack{T\text{ is
an SSYT}\\\text{of shape }y/x;\\\text{all entries in row }i\text{ of }T\text{
are }>i}}\ \ \sum_{\substack{P\text{ is an anti-coSSYT}\\\text{of shape
}z/y;\\\text{all entries in row }i\text{ of }P\text{ are }>i}}a^{w\left(
T\right)  }a^{w\left(  P\right)  }.
\label{eq.darij2.3}
\tag{5}
\end{align}
Let us combine the two summation signs on the right hand side into one, by
compiling the corresponding indices $T$ and $P$ into a single "broken
tableau". Namely, we define a broken tableau of shape $z/y/x$ to be a
tableau of shape $z/x$ whose restriction to $z/y$ is an anti-coSSYT whereas
its restriction to $y/x$ is an SSYT. Then, the broken tableaux $R$ of shape
$z/y/x$ are in bijection with the pairs $\left(  T,P\right)  $ of an SSYT $T$
of shape $y/x$ and an anti-coSSYT $P$ of shape $z/y$ (and the bijection simply
sets $T:=R\mid_{y/x}$ and $P:=R\mid_{z/y}$). Thus,
\begin{align*}
& \sum_{\substack{T\text{ is an SSYT}\\\text{of shape }y/x;\\\text{all entries
in row }i\text{ of }T\text{ are }>i}}\ \ \sum_{\substack{P\text{ is an
anti-coSSYT}\\\text{of shape }z/y;\\\text{all entries in row }i\text{ of
}P\text{ are }>i}}a^{w\left(  T\right)  }a^{w\left(  P\right)  }\\
& =\sum_{\substack{R\text{ is a broken tableau of shape }z/y/x;\\\text{all
entries in row }i\text{ of }T\text{ are }>i}}\ \ a^{w\left(  R\right)  }.
\end{align*}
Hence, \eqref{eq.darij2.3} rewrites as
\begin{equation}
\Lambda\left(  y,x\right)  \Pi\left(  z,y\right)  =\left(  -1\right)
^{\left\vert z/y\right\vert }\sum_{\substack{R\text{ is a broken tableau of
shape }z/y/x;\\\text{all entries in row }i\text{ of }T\text{ are }
>i}}\ \ a^{w\left(  R\right)  }.
\label{eq.darij2.4}
\tag{6}
\end{equation}
Now, keep $x$ and $z$ fixed, but not $y$. Our goal is to prove that
$\sum\limits_{y}\Lambda\left(  y,x\right)  \Pi\left(  z,y\right)  =1_{x=z}$,
where the sum ranges over all partitions $y$ satisfying $x\subseteq y\subseteq
z$. For $x=z$, this is obvious (the sum on the left hand side has just a
single addend, and this addend is $1$). Thus, we WLOG assume that $x\neq z$.
We must show that $\sum\limits_{y}\Lambda\left(  y,x\right)  \Pi\left(
z,y\right)  =0$ in this case.
But \eqref{eq.darij2.4} yields
\begin{align}
& \sum\limits_{y}\Lambda\left(  y,x\right)  \Pi\left(  z,y\right)
\nonumber\\
& =\sum\limits_{y}\left(  -1\right)  ^{\left\vert z/y\right\vert }
\sum_{\substack{R\text{ is a broken tableau of shape }z/y/x;\\\text{all
entries in row }i\text{ of }T\text{ are }>i}}\ \ a^{w\left(  R\right)
}\nonumber\\
& =\sum_{\substack{R\text{ is a tableau of shape }z/x;\\\text{all entries in
row }i\text{ of }T\text{ are }>i}}\ \ \left(  \sum
\limits_{\substack{y;\\R\text{ is a broken tableau}\\\text{of shape }
z/y/x}}\left(  -1\right)  ^{\left\vert z/y\right\vert }\right)  a^{w\left(
R\right)  }
\label{eq.darij2.5}
\tag{7}
\end{align}
(keep in mind that the tableau $R$ is not bound by any increasing/decreasing
conditions, so the inner sum here will often be empty). It will thus suffice
to show that each tableau $R$ of shape $z/x$ satisfies
\begin{equation}
\sum\limits_{\substack{y;\\R\text{ is a broken tableau}\\\text{of shape
}z/y/x}}\left(  -1\right)  ^{\left\vert z/y\right\vert }=0
\label{eq.darij2.6}
\tag{8}
\end{equation}
(because this means that the inner sum in \eqref{eq.darij2.5} is zero, and
therefore the entire outer sum is $0$ as well).
So let us prove \eqref{eq.darij2.6} then. Let $R$ be a tableau of shape $z/x$.
We translate our situation into the language of my paper Double posets and
the antipode of QSym
(arXiv:1509.08355v3). We define the
double poset $\mathbf{E}=\left(  E,<_{1},<_{2}\right)  $ as follows: As a set,
$E$ is the set of all cells of the skew Young diagram $z/x$. The first partial
order $<_{1}$ is given by
\begin{align*}
\left(  a,b\right)  \ <_{1}\ \left(  c,d\right)  \ \Longleftrightarrow
\ \left(  a\leq c\text{ and }b\leq d\text{ and }\left(  a,b\right)
\neq\left(  c,d\right)  \right)  .
\end{align*}
The second partial order $<_{2}$ is given by
\begin{align*}
\left(  a,b\right)  \ <_{2}\ \left(  c,d\right)  \ \Longleftrightarrow
\ \left(  a\leq c\text{ and }b\geq d\text{ and }\left(  a,b\right)
\neq\left(  c,d\right)  \right)  .
\end{align*}
This $\mathbf{E}$ is a tertispecial double poset (see Example 3.3 in loc.
cit., but notice that our cells $\left(  a,b\right)  $ correspond to $\left(
b,a\right)  $ in the notation of loc. cit.) and satisfies $\left\vert
E\right\vert >0$ (since $x\neq z$). Let $>_{1}$ and $>_{2}$ denote the
opposite relations of $<_{1}$ and $<_{2}$, respectively. Pick an integer $M$
that is larger than each entry of the tableau $R$. Then, Lemma 6.5 in loc.
cit. says that any map $\pi:E\rightarrow\left\{  1,2,3,\ldots\right\}  $
satisfies
\begin{equation}
\sum_{\substack{\left(  P,Q\right)  \in\operatorname{Adm}{\mathbf{E}}
;\\\pi\mid_{P}\text{ is a }\left(  P,>_{1},<_{2}\right)  \text{-partition;}
\\\pi\mid_{Q}\text{ is a }\left(  Q,<_{1},<_{2}\right)  \text{-partition}
}}\left(  -1\right)  ^{\left\vert P\right\vert }=0,
\label{eq.darij2.9}
\tag{9}
\end{equation}
where we use the notations of loc. cit. again (see Definition 5.5 (a) for the
meaning of $\operatorname*{Adm}\mathbf{E}$, and Definition 3.2 for the notion
of "$\mathbf{E}$-partitions"). However, the pairs $\left(  P,Q\right)
\in\operatorname{Adm}{\mathbf{E}}$ (called "admissible partitions of
$\mathbf{E}$" in loc. cit.) are in bijection with the partitions $y$
satisfying $x\subseteq y\subseteq z$: Indeed, if $y$ is a partition of the
latter type, then the corresponding pair $\left(  P,Q\right)  \in
\operatorname{Adm}{\mathbf{E}}$ is given by $P=\left\{  \text{cells of
}y/x\right\}  $ and $Q=\left\{  \text{cells of }z/y\right\}  $. Thus, we can
rewrite the equality \eqref{eq.darij2.9} as
\begin{equation}
\sum_{\substack{y;\\\pi\mid_{y/x}\text{ is a }\left(  y/x,>_{1},<_{2}\right)
\text{-partition;}\\\pi\mid_{z/y}\text{ is a }\left(  z/y,<_{1},<_{2}\right)
\text{-partition}}}\left(  -1\right)  ^{\left\vert y/x\right\vert
}=0,
\label{eq.darij2.9b}
\tag{10}
\end{equation}
where the sum ranges over all partitions $y$ satisfying $x\subseteq y\subseteq
z$, and where we write $y/x$ and $z/y$ for the sets $\left\{  \text{cells of
}y/x\right\}  $ and $\left\{  \text{cells of }z/y\right\}  $, respectively.
The equality \eqref{eq.darij2.9b} has a twin, which says that any map
$\pi:E\rightarrow\left\{  1,2,3,\ldots\right\}  $ satisfies
\begin{equation}
\sum_{\substack{y;\\\pi\mid_{y/x}\text{ is a }\left(  y/x,<_{1},>_{2}\right)
\text{-partition;}\\\pi\mid_{z/y}\text{ is a }\left(  z/y,>_{1},>_{2}\right)
\text{-partition}}}\left(  -1\right)  ^{\left\vert y/x\right\vert
}=0.
\label{eq.darij2.9c}
\tag{11}
\end{equation}
Indeed, we can easily derive \eqref{eq.darij2.9c} from \eqref{eq.darij2.9b},
by defining $M$ to be the largest value of $\pi$ and then replacing each value
$k$ of $\pi$ by $M+1-k$ (so that all the inequalities in the conditions
"$\pi\mid_{y/x}$ is a $\left(  y/x,>_{1},<_{2}\right)  $-partition" and
"$\pi\mid_{z/y}$ is a $\left(  z/y,<_{1},<_{2}\right)  $-partition" get
reversed).
The tableau $R$ is a map from $E$ to $\left\{  1,2,3,\ldots\right\}  $. Thus,
we can apply \eqref{eq.darij2.9c} to $\pi=R$, and obtain
\begin{equation}
\sum_{\substack{y;\\R\mid_{y/x}\text{ is a }\left(  y/x,<_{1},>_{2}\right)
\text{-partition;}\\R\mid_{z/y}\text{ is a }\left(  z/y,>_{1},>_{2}\right)
\text{-partition}}}\left(  -1\right)  ^{\left\vert y/x\right\vert
}=0.
\label{eq.darij2.9d}
\tag{12}
\end{equation}
The condition "$R\mid_{y/x}$ is a $\left(  y/x,<_{1},>_{2}\right)
$-partition" under the summation sign here is saying precisely that the
restriction $R\mid_{y/x}$ is an SSYT of shape $y/x$. Likewise, the condition
"$R\mid_{z/y}$ is a $\left(  z/y,>_{1},>_{2}\right)  $-partition" is saying
precisely that the restriction $R\mid_{z/y}$ is an anti-coSSYT of shape $z/y$.
Thus, the two conditions taken together are saying that $R$ is a broken
tableau of shape $z/y/x$. In light of this, we can rewrite the sum on the left
hand side of \eqref{eq.darij2.9d} as $\sum\limits_{\substack{y;\\R\text{ is a
broken tableau}\\\text{of shape }z/y/x}}\left(  -1\right)  ^{\left\vert
y/x\right\vert }$. Thus, \eqref{eq.darij2.9d} rewrites as
\begin{equation}
\sum\limits_{\substack{y;\\R\text{ is a broken tableau}\\\text{of shape
}z/y/x}}\left(  -1\right)  ^{\left\vert y/x\right\vert }
=0.
\label{eq.darij2.10}
\tag{13}
\end{equation}
This is almost the desired equality \eqref{eq.darij2.6}. The only difference
is that the addend is $\left(  -1\right)  ^{\left\vert y/x\right\vert }$
instead of $\left(  -1\right)  ^{\left\vert z/y\right\vert }$. But this makes
little difference, since $\left\vert z/y\right\vert +\left\vert y/x\right\vert
=\left\vert z/x\right\vert $ and thus $\left\vert y/x\right\vert =\left\vert
z/x\right\vert -\left\vert z/y\right\vert $, so that $\left(  -1\right)
^{\left\vert y/x\right\vert }=\left(  -1\right)  ^{\left\vert z/x\right\vert
-\left\vert z/y\right\vert }=\left(  -1\right)  ^{\left\vert z/y\right\vert
}\left(  -1\right)  ^{\left\vert z/x\right\vert }$, and thus we can rewrite
\eqref{eq.darij2.10} as
\begin{align*}
\sum\limits_{\substack{y;\\R\text{ is a broken tableau}\\\text{of shape
}z/y/x}}\left(  -1\right)  ^{\left\vert z/y\right\vert }\left(  -1\right)
^{\left\vert z/x\right\vert }=0.
\end{align*}
Factoring the constant sign $\left(  -1\right)  ^{\left\vert z/x\right\vert }$
out of here, we arrive precisely at \eqref{eq.darij2.6}, as desired.
Some comments:

Your flagging conditions can be generalized significantly, adding $2\ell$ or $3\ell$ degrees of freedom where $\ell$ is the number of rows. All you need to ensure is that when the two tableaux are combined into the broken tableau, the conditions end up the same.

The proof of Lemma 6.5 in loc. cit. is combinatorial, relying on a sign-reversing involution. The involution is easy to describe: Let $E_{\min}$ be the set of all elements $e \in E$ for which $\pi\left(e\right)$ is minimum. Pick an element $f$ of $E_{\min}$ that is minimal with respect to the partial order $<_2$. Then, the involution moves $f$ from $P$ to $Q$ or vice versa. Note that the involution depends on the choice of $f$, so you need to choose $f$ in advance. You can easily adapt this involution to work directly as a proof of \eqref{eq.darij2.9c}, by replacing "$\pi\left(e\right)$ is minimum" by "$\pi\left(e\right)$ is maximum".



Thank you, I will work through this to extend to cylindrical. I will cite your article and this post in the article.

@ThomasKojar: You're welcome! Cylindric semistandard tableaux can just as easily be interpreted as $\mathbf{E}$-partitions for appropriate double posets $\mathbf{E}$.

Unless I'm missing something, the definition of $\Pi$ is in terms of tableaux of shape $z'/y/$, so if we transpose to make the shapes fit together the flag conditions should apply to columns, not rows.

@ZachH: But the flag conditions are on columns before the transposition, aren't they? The flagged $e$-Jacobi-Trudi formula is column-flagged.

I see, I misread the definition of $\Pi$, which is indeed in terms of column flagged tableaux. Thanks for clarifying!

Edit: As pointed out by Darij, I was previously using an incorrect definition of $\Pi$. With the corrected definition, my argument works as intended.
The proof I mentioned is part of an abandoned section in an soon-to-be-posted preprint (joint with Adam Gregory and Tianyi Yu), so I've sketched it below.
If I understand correctly, we have
$$
\Lambda(\lambda,\mu) = \sum_{\substack{T \in \mathrm{SSYT}(\lambda/\mu)\\ i < T_{ij} \leq n}} a^{\mathrm{wt}(T)}
\quad \mbox{and} \quad
\Pi(\lambda,\mu) = \sum_{\substack{T \in \mathrm{SSYT}(\lambda'/\mu')\\ 1 \leq T_{ij} < n-j}} a^{\mathrm{wt}(T)} \mid_{a_i \mapsto -a_{n+1-i}}.
$$
Let $x_i = a_{n+1-i}$ for $i \in [n]$.
Define the complement of the partition $\lambda$ as
$$\lambda^c = (n - \lambda_n, n-\lambda_{n-1}, \dots, n-\lambda_1).
$$
Tableaux of shape $\lambda/\mu$ can be viewed as reverse tableaux of shape $\mu^c/\lambda^c$, but we have reversed the variables so
$$
\Lambda(\lambda,\mu) = \sum_{\substack{T \in \mathrm{SSYT}(\mu^c/\lambda)\\ 1 \leq T_{ij} \leq n+1-i}} x^{\mathrm{wt}(T)}.
$$
We can also view the negative variables in the formula for $\Pi(\lambda,\mu)$ as arising from negative entries, so $T_{ij} = -4$ would contribute $-x_4$.
Then
$$
\Pi(\lambda,\mu) = \sum_{\substack{T \in \mathrm{SSYT}((\mu^c)'/(\lambda^c)')\\ -(n+1-j) \leq T_{ij} \leq -1}} x^{\mathrm{wt}(T)}.
$$
Both formulas have been rewritten to express what are to my eye more natural flaggings.
Moreover, we can undo the transpose in the $\Pi(\lambda,\mu)$ by working with co-semistandard tableaux, which are column weak and row strict.
In the sum
$$
\sum_{\mu \subseteq \nu \subseteq \lambda} \Lambda(\nu,\mu) \cdot \Pi(\lambda,\nu),
$$
each monomial corresponds to a tableau $T_1$ for $\Lambda(\nu,\mu)$ and a tableau $T_2$ for $\Pi(\lambda,\nu)$.
By concatenating $T_1$ with the transpose of $T_2$, we get a tableau formula
$$
\sum_{\mu \subseteq \nu \subseteq \lambda} \Lambda(\nu,\mu) \cdot \Pi(\lambda,\nu) = \sum_{T} x^{\mathrm{wt}(T)}
$$
where the sum is over tableaux of shape $\mu^c/\lambda^c$ so that:

the entries of $T$ are integers that weakly increase across rows and down columns;
negative entries are column strict;
positive entries are row strict;
if $T_{ij} < 0$, then $-(n+1-i) \leq T_{ij}$;
if $T_{ij} > 0$, then $T_{ij} \leq n+1-i$.

Changing the sign of one entry in such a tableau will change the sign of $x^{\mathrm{wt}(T)}$ but not the monomial.
When $\mu = \lambda$, the sum is clearly $1$.
Therefore, our goal is to show when $\mu \neq \lambda$ that every such tableau has an entry who's sign can change.
In doing so, by swapping the sign of the highest such entry, we obtain a sign-reversing involution.
What does an entry whose sign can change look like?
We need a cell $(i,j)$ so that
$$
(\dagger)\ \ |T_{i{-1}\,j}| \geq |T_{ij}| < |T_{i{+}1\,j}| \quad \mbox{and} \quad
|T_{i\, j{-1}}| > |T_{ij}| \leq |T_{i\,j{+1}}|
$$
where the conditions are satisfied vacuously if comparisons are made between cells not in the diagram.
Additionally, we need to satisfy both flag conditions, but this occurs automatically as they are identical after taking absolute value.
It's not too hard to an entry satisfying $(\dagger)$.
Let $i$ be the lowest row containing a positive entry and  $(i,j)$ be the first cell in that row so that $T_{ij} > 0$.
If $T_{ij}$ doesn't satisfy $(\dagger)$, then we must have $|T_{i\,j{-1}}| \leq |T_{ij}|$.
Now let $k$ be the first value so that $|T_{k\,j{-1}}| < |T_{k{+1}\,j{-1}}|$.
Then
$$
|T_{i\,j{-1}}| \geq \dots \geq  |T_{k\,j{-1}}| \quad \mbox{and} \quad |T_{ij}| \leq \dots \leq |T_{kj}|,
$$
the former chain by construction of $k$ and the latter since $T_{ij} > 0$.
Therefore, $|T_{k\,j{-1}}| \leq |T_{kj}|$, so we are in the same case but in a lower row of the tableau.
Since the tableau is finite, iterating this argument must eventually terminate, giving us a cell satisfying $(\dagger)$.

Without reading this in full, I feel that if your flag conditions on the positive and the negative entries don't match, then you must have done something wrong (an easy thing to do in this problem).

Since one is for columns and the other for rows, I don't think we should expect the flag conditions to match.

Right, but the Jacobi-Trudi formula that involves $e$-functions also involves conjugate partitions, so I think that any transformation that will make the shapes fit together will also make the flag conditions match. Or am I getting things wrong?

I'm working off the definition of $\Pi$ in terms of tableaux from the original problem. I would not be surprised if the translation from Jacobi-Trudi to tableaux there is incorrect. With your assumptions, it seems my argument should go through (and is essentially the same as yours, albeit less general).

I think both the Jacobi-Trudi formula and the tableaux formulas for $\Pi$ in the original post (in its current version) are correct. Where exactly do you see an inconsistency?

See my remark on your answer: "Unless I'm missing something, the definition of $\Pi$ is in terms of tableaux of shape $z′/y'$, so if we transpose to make the shapes fit together the flag conditions should apply to columns, not rows."
